# How to prove an angle equals to $90^°$ algebraicly

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

Let $ABCD$ be an isosceles trapezoid. Let $P$ be the intersection of its diagonals. the line $DA$ meets the circumcircle of $APB$ at $M$. Let $L$ be a point on $AB$ such that $LD=LB$ and $K$ be a point on $DL$ such that $KLAM$ is cyclic. Denote by $J$ the intersection of $KA$ and $ML$.

Prove that $\angle BPJ =90^°$

Sorry I haven't tried to solve this, it's really hard but I did a geometric interpretation and the angle is right. [image]

Comment: "I did a geometric interpretation and the angle is right." You don't know that the angle is right, unless you have a proof that the angle is right. So, which is it – do you have a geometric proof, or do you not really know that the angle is right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No I should do it geometric proof but I couldn't so I checked using geogebra and I found it really a right angle

Comment: And geogebra has no facility for telling you how it knows it's really a right angle? (and why do you now say you want a geometric proof, when in the title of the question you ask for an algebraic proof?)

Comment: If you haven't even tried, you're not going to learn anything from an answer, even if you get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @pppl234plp for forcing me to try out this wonderful problem. Here goes the solution :-

We avoid directed angles and stick with this configuration.

Firstly note that $DA\times DM=DL \times DK=DP \times DB$ so that by converse of the Power of Point, we get $LPBK$ is cyclic.

Next, $\angle LBP=\angle LKP =\angle LDP$ so that $PK=PD=PC$ where the last equality comes from the fact that $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid.

Next we claim that $ALPD$ is cyclic.

Proof:Note that $\angle LDP=\angle LBP=\angle ABP=\angle BAP$ (isosceles trapezoid) $=\angle LAP$ and the claim follows.

We now claim that $DK=DC$.

Notice that $\angle KPD=180-\angle KPB=180-\angle KLB=180-\angle ALD=180-\angle APD=\angle DPC$.

Now, $KP=KC$, segment $PD$ is common and $\angle KPD=\angle DPC$ so that triangles $KDP$ and $PDC$ are congruent, and hence $KD=DC$ and the claim follows.

Note now that $\angle BKL=\angle LPD=\angle MAL$ so that $M,K,B$ are collinear.

This readily gives $P$ is the miquel point of the complete quadrialteral $LAMKDB$

As we have the complete quadrilateral $LAMKDB$ and as $LAMK$ is cyclic hence, $J$ and $P$ are swap each other under the inversion $\Psi$ centered at the center of $\odot (MKAL)$ and radius the same as of $\odot (MKAL)$, so that if we let $O$ denote center of $\odot (MKAL)$ then $O,J,P$ are collinear.

As $DB$ is the polar of $J$ with respect to $\odot (MKAL)$ (Brokard's Theorem), line $OJ=$ line $JP$ is orthogonal to $BD$ and the conclusion follows.